# Translating a fixed-point operator to Haskell language

Tags: javascript, haskell, types, code-translation, fixpoint-combinators

I am trying to translate this JS fixed-point operator into Haskell.

JS:

```js
const fix = F => {
    const D = X => F(
        t => X(X)(t)
    )
    return D(D)
};
```

My attempt is (Haskell):

```hs
fix' f = d d
  where
    d x = f (\t -> x x t)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘(t2 -> t3) -> t4’
              with actual type ‘p’
because type variables ‘t2’, ‘t3’, ‘t4’ would escape their scope
These (rigid, skolem) type variables are bound by the inferred type of d :: (t1 -> t2 -> t3) -> t4
```

Does someone know what's happening here ?

Comment: It's a well-known problem that fixpoint combinators like Y can't be well-typed in Haskell. Specifically, something of the form `x x` requires `x` to have two conflicting types simultaneously. In dynamic languages, this doesn't matter because you just don't _care_ what the type is, only that you can use the value in some way. But a Haskell compiler does care. However there's no need for such combinators, because Haskell's solution `fix f = let x = f x in x` is more elegant anyway, and has no typing difficulties (but does require lazy evaluation).

Comment: Self-application like `x x` fails in haskell, since it can't be well-typed. There is some sorcery to make some variant of it work, but you don't need that. To define a working fixed point operator, just use recursion e.g. `fix f = f (fix f)` (more efficient ones exist, but this is the simplest).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the self-application `d d`, `d` is both a function, of some type `a -> r`, and its argument, of type `a`. Thus the two types must be one and the same, `a ~ (a -> r)`.

Haskell wants to know its types in full upfront so it keeps substituting one for another ending up with an infinite type.

Infinite types aren't allowed in Haskell, but recursive types are allowed.

All we need to do here is to name that recursive type:

```hs
newtype T r = D { app :: T r -> r }
```

Now `T r` is both a type of a function and its argument, for some result type `r`.

Here `T` is a type constructor, and `D` its data constructor, `D :: (T r -> r) -> T r`.

The above *record syntax* defines a new data type (here though with the keyword `newtype`, not `data`) and names its single field as `app`. It also defines `app` as an accessor function, `app :: T r -> (T r -> r)`. <sub>(It's kind of an inverse of `D`, and oftentimes one sees such functions named with the prefix of "un", like `app` could have been named `unD`. But here `app` makes sense, as we will see later.)</sub>

For a value `x` of type `T r`, `x :: T r`, this means that `x` is / matches up with / some value `D g` where `(g = app x) :: T r -> r`, i.e. `app` simply unwraps the data constructor `D` to get to the underlying value (a function) `g`: `x = D g ; app x = app (D g) = g`. That's how the record syntax works in Haskell.

Now we can write

```hs
{- fix' f = d d
     where
       d x = f (\t -> x x t)   -- applying x to x can't be typed!
-}

fix1 :: ((t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t
fix1 f = d (D d)
  where
    d x = f (\t -> app x x t)   -- `app`ing x to x is well-typed!

fix2 :: ((t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t
fix2 f = d (D d)
  where
    d (D y) = f (\t -> y (D y) t)

fix3 :: ((t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t) -> t1 -> t
fix3 f = f (\t -> d (D d) t)
  where
    d (D y) = f (\t -> y (D y) t)

fix4 :: (t -> t) -> t
fix4 f = f (d (D d))
  where
    d (D y) = f (y (D y))
```

all work. The last one even has the same type as the built-in `fix`.

But Haskell doesn't only have recursive *types*. It also has recursion itself. An entity *is* allowed to refer to *itself* in its own *definition*.

Thus as the comments say we don't really need to emulate recursion by self-application of a value passed as an argument. We can just use recursively the function being defined, itself:

```hs
fix0 :: (t -> t) -> t
fix0 f  =  f (fix0 f)
```

Or we can use a recursively defined value:

```hs
y :: (t -> t) -> t
y f  =  x  where  { x = f x }
```

---

Regarding the error, the *second* type error [you get](https://ideone.com/TiOvpd),

```hs
prog.hs:3:22: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        t1 ~ t1 -> t2 -> t3
    • In the first argument of ‘x’, namely ‘x’
      In the expression: x x t
      In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘(\ t -> x x t)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        t :: t2 (bound at prog.hs:3:15)
        x :: t1 -> t2 -> t3 (bound at prog.hs:3:7)
        d :: (t1 -> t2 -> t3) -> t4 (bound at prog.hs:3:5)
  |
3 |     d x = f (\t -> x x t)
  |                      ^
```

seems more to-the-point / helpful / than the one you included.

Comment: Thank you so much, again ! Could you explain this line "app x x t" ?

Comment: I've edited. :) `app x x t` is the same as `case x of (D g) -> g (D g) t`. Haskell's application is curried, so `a b c` is really `(a b) c`. For the same reason, the type of `a :: b -> c -> r`, is really `a :: b -> (c -> r)`. It is said that in Haskell, application associates on the left and type arrows associate on the right.